# For Vivienne. A Very Short Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

Your answer should explain all the parts of this riddle.

> Try
>   To try,
>   Vi

The answer (as implied by the second tag) is a single short English word.

Comment: I probably could have made this a better riddle but I got carried away with the challenge of presenting a viable riddle with only four words and ten characters which must, I think, be close to the theoretical minimum. The title, I am afraid, is a private joke. My friend Vivienne is of average height but thinks of herself as lacking sufficient verticality.

Comment: Tell Vivienne not to sell herself short.

Comment: Apparently a very short riddle is also a riddle open to much interpretation...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit**: Based on the comment from the question poser:

> You are within a league of the finish line.

I could possibly see the solution being:

> league

Try

> In rugby, a "try" is worth 5 points.

To try,

> Let's go ahead and make two of them now 5 5

Vi

> And then interpret this as a Roman Numeral 6

Then we see

> A league is equal to 5556m.

---

<sup>old answer left for posterity</sup>

This is

> The number of days in a leap year.

Try

> a homonym of the prefix "tri-", which indicates 3.

To Try,

> a homonym of "two" and then "tri-" again, which indicates 6.

Vi

> interpreted as Roman numerals, we get 6.

Composing this gives us

> 366: the number of days in a leap year (such as 2016).

It's not yet clear to me if the title is related.

Comment: oh my goodness.

Comment: Aaaggh! The 'league' reference was in reply to my answer - I even checked it up! It was staring me in my face!! Can't believe I missed it... Well done! ... I was thinking to myself - that's odd... a league is miles out and not even close... He must mean something... AAghhh :0)

Comment: Clearly, you are in a league of your own. Well done!

Answer (score 6):

Try

> Three (as in tri)

To try

> two threes

Vi

> 6 (VI is 6 in Roman Numerals)

So Vivienne really likes

> Mazdas? Specifically the Mazda 323 and Mazda 6

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is an

> Exception

Two

> Try blocks

between a

> to

in

> Vi (or vim)

will result in an

> Exception

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> BMW model# 525 or 526

How did I get there?
TRY

> = 5. a try in rugby is worth **5** points

TO TRY

> = 25

comma

> = or

Vi

> = 6

Comment: Your answer could easily be converted to what I had in mind. You are within a league of the finish line.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer:

> Beef
>  The second (TO[2]), fifth (TRY[5]), fifth (TRY[5]) and sixth (Vi) letters of the alphabet.
>  TRY = 5 because a try scores 5 points in rugby. Based off my first answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word is

> Plan / Scheme

Try to Try

> If we read this as "Try to Try", we get to something extremely different than if we were to pause after the first try. Essentially, this hints that the narrator is telling someone to try, however, not to do x. He's telling someone to try to even attempt at doing x. Incentivating/Motivating of sorts. Before trying to do something, a plan(Trying to Try) must be formed, and only then it's executed (the 2nd try).

Vi

> I'm somewhat inclined to believe that this is misderection and just a calling. Usually on letters the receipient is identified by ",receipientName", and as Vi can be short for Vivienne, that's my reasoning.